# Uncaught TypeError: rand.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error on browser console

> Uncaught TypeError: rand.slice is not a function

***JavaScript***

```
var rand, date;
date = Date.now();
rand = Math.random() * Math.random();
rand = Math.floor(date * rand);
rand = rand.slice(-5); 
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = rand;
```

I'm not able to figure it out what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you can't directly slice a number.. you can convert to string first then `slice` after

like this:

```
rand = rand.toString().slice(-5)
```

[JavaScript Array slice() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

[JavaScript String slice() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)

Answer (score 10):

Try using `rand = rand.toString().slice(-5);` instead of `rand = rand.slice(-5);`

`slice` can be used either on `array` or `string` and not on numbers.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
rand = (rand+'').slice(-5);
```

This will generate random number that will be converted to string by combining it with +'' and then we can call slice function